# DSOFramer will not show context menu in Excel 2010

Tags: c++, windows, excel-2010

I am embedding Excel in winform using DSOFramer control. 
In case of Excel 2010 the context menu on right mouse button click will not open.
It looks as if the control loses focus on right click. 
I edited the DsoFramer source code before so I am comfortable with it. Anybody know of any possible hack in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
STDMETHODIMP_(void) CDsoFramerControl::OnCtrlFocusChange(BOOL fCtlGotFocus, HWND hFocusWnd)
{
    //TRACE2("CDsoFramerControl::OnCtrlFocusChange(fCtlGotFocus=%d, hwndCurFocus=%x)\n", fCtlGotFocus, hFocusWnd);
 //   if (!(m_fInFocusChange) && ((fCtlGotFocus) || !IsWindowChild(m_hwnd, hFocusWnd)))
 //   {
 //       OnUIFocusChange(fCtlGotFocus);
 //   }
}
```